# Javascript regex capturing words and separators in groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression in Javascript capturing two groups. The first one is capturing a word `Hello` and the second one is capturing the following separators, like `!`, and so on given a string `Hello! I hear you`.

This is the expression I am using:

```
/(\b[^\s]+\b)?(\W+)/g
```

[The example is accessible here](http://regexr.com/3bohs). The problem I have is that I would like to capture the last word in the source string (to capture group 1) for cases in which there is no following separator character. In the sample I link to you can see that the last word `part` is not captured.

I have tried a number of variants, but I end up in infinitely number of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:  How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/sP8gX0/2):

(\b[^\s]+\b)?(\W*)         -->matches empty string (as noted by @anubhava)

(\b[^\s]+\b)?(?:(\W+)|$)   -->does not match empty string

```js
var re = /(\b[^\s]+\b)?(?:(\W+)|$)/g; 
var str = '.Balch Creek is a 3.5-mile (5.6 km) tributary of the Willamette River in the U.S. state of Oregon. Beginning at the crest of the Tualatin Mountains, the creek flows generally east down a canyon and through Forest Park, a large municipal park in Portland. It then enters a pipe and remains underground until reaching the river. Danford Balch, after  vegetation. Sixty-two species of mammals and more than 112 species of birds use Forest Park. A small population of coastal cutthroat trout resides in the stream, which in 2005 was the only major water body in Portland that met state standards for bacteria, temperature, and dissolved oxygen. Although nature reserves cover much of the upper and middle parts of the watershed, industrial sites dominate the lower part';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "Group 1: " + m[1] + "<br/>Group 2: " + m[2] + "<br/><br/>";
    
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Exactly that one I have actually tried, but I get an infinite amount of matches for that one for some reason.

Comment: I'm confused - I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to capture then.  Can you post what you expect to capture given an example input?

Comment: No, you are exactly right what I am trying to capture. But the problem is, as you can see in your linked page, that it says "Infinite" in red. So that gives me a problem when running it in Javascript. It hangs when I do `while (matches = regex.exec($scope.source))`.

Comment: Why infinite? What problem do you have? Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7kzkqpx/).

Comment: Ok, just updated with another suggestion.  Should work, similar to @stribizhev 's JSFiddle...

Comment: @stribizhev that `re.lastIndex++;` did the trick. I must admit (as if that isn't obvious) I don't fully understand the exec method in Javascript.

Comment: @NumericOverflow: I suggest you add the JS code to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/(\S+)(\W*)/g
```

`(\W*)` in last group will make it match 0 or more non-word characters.

Also no need to use word boundaries around `\S+`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI7pV6/2)

Comment: Thanks, but there are a few problems with this solution: first) The first dot is not captured in $2. second) I would actually want to capture the entire `3.5-mile` in one single $1.

Comment: Getting closer :). Still, the "word" part, i.e. capture group $1, should start with `\b` and finish with `\b`.

Comment: Using `\b` around `\S+` will make it skip DOT from `.Balch`

Comment: Also note that `(\b\S+\b)?(\W*)` will make it match empty string `""` also [as in this example](https://regex101.com/r/cI7pV6/3)